# javascript matches too many times

Tags: javascript, regex

I got problems with this regex. I want to return the first occurrence of this pattern `#2344....`. But somehow it is returning all occurrences.

```
var title = '#34 #24 pofejwopwefjopewfjpfeijefow'
pointsRegEx = /(#\d+){1}/;
points = title.match(pointsRegEx);
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/KbGVU/1

Comment: How about /#\d+/ ? Could you show more examples?

Comment: It worked, stranged that I couldn't encapsulate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is working fine.  In your regex, you have `()`.  This creates a group.  `.match` returns an array.  The 1st element is the result matched by the entire regex, the other elements are each group from your regex.

`.match` is returning you `['#34','#34']` because the 1st is the entire regex, and the 2nd is the group in your regex `(#\d+)`.

Note: `{1}` is not needed, as it will match 1 match by default.

The properties of the array returned from `.match` is documented here: [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Description).

Comment: @Woho87 You should accept this as the correct answer if it helped you. Doing that will be helpful to others with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Got chya... you don't need to match a match witha () grouping...

http://jsfiddle.net/KbGVU/3/

`/#\d*/` ought to do it

Comment: I think he wants a number after the hash. So /#\d+/ would better.

Comment: Those are the same thing, one is just more greedy.